# How to deploy a Helm 3 chart using C#

Tags: c#, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

What is the best way to deploy a Helm chart using C#? Helm 3 is written in go and I could not find a C# wrapper, any advise on that? Thank you.

Comment: Can you share some details why you need language specific details? I used helm 3 to deploy Java, Nodejs and Python based applications. It is very simple. "helm upgrade --install [deployment] [chartdirectory]"

Comment: I am automating the workflow of setting up basic components in a new kubernetes namespace. A frontend will trigger the workflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helm is written in Go so unless you want to get incredibly fancy your best bet is running it as a subprocess like normal. A medium-fancy solution would be using one of the many Helm operators and then using a C# Kubernetes api client library to set the objects.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. For now I will just do the variable substitution of kubernetes manifest files in C# and use the kubernetes api client library for deployment.